# How do I retrieve values of a taxonomy field inside a field collection of a profile2 node?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, users, entities

Can someone tell me how can I retrieve values of a taxonomy field inside a field collection of a profile2 node?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using entity_metadata_wrapper to load the profile2 entity.

You could then drill down to the field value on the field_collection.

Something like:

```
$profile = profile2_load_by_user($account, 'main');
// Use entity metadata wrapper, because it's awesome.
$profile_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('profile2', $profile);
// We can access the term as the "value" of the field_collection child field
$term = $profile_wrapper->get('field_my_field_collection')->field_my_taxonomy_term->value();
// Just print out the term for now
drupal_set_message('<pre>'.var_export($term,1).'</pre>');
```

Comment: Thanks ... this is what I needed with a slight modifications according to my specific requirements.

Comment: it seems when $profile is null it will raise `EntityMetadataWrapperException: Invalid data value given` on entity_metadata_wrapper(). For this simple !empty($profile) is enough. am I right?